# Passing on condition to d3.dispatch

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, events

I am trying to see how can I author an interaction to `d3.dispatch`.

Without dispatch, the interaction is following

```js
const data = [
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 2 },
    { "id": 3 },
    { "id": 4 },
    { "id": 5 },
    { "id": 6 },
    { "id": 7 },
    { "id": 8 }
];

const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const width = 600;
const height = 450;

const posX = 40;
const posY = 20;
const heightRect = 40;
const widthRect = 40;
const padding = 10;

const svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('xmlns', svgns)
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

const bgRect = svg.append('rect')
    .classed('boundary', true)
    .attr('x', '0')
    .attr('y', '0')
    .attr('width', `${width}`)
    .attr('height', `${height}`)
    .attr('fill', `#E6E6E6`);

//-------------BUILD COLOR SCALE---------------------------//
const interpolatorSequentialMultiHueName = [
    'd3.interpolateViridis'
]

const xColorScale = d3.scaleSequential().domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.id))
    .interpolator(eval(`${interpolatorSequentialMultiHueName[0]}`));

//-------------BUILD RECT---------------------------//   

const rect = svg.append('g')
    .classed('rectContainer', true)
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .join('rect')
    .attr('x', `${posX}`)
    .attr('y', ((d, i) => posY + heightRect * i + padding * i))
    .attr('width', `${widthRect}`)
    .attr('height', `${heightRect}`)
    .attr('fill', (d => xColorScale(d.id)))
    .attr('opacity', '0.5');

//listener
const listener =
    d3.select('rect')
    .clone()
    .raise()
    .attr('x', `${posX}`)
    .attr('y', ((d, i) => { return posY }))
    .attr('width', `${widthRect}`)
    .attr('height', ((d, i) => { const node = rect.nodes(); const len = node.length - 1; return node[len].y.baseVal.value + node[len].height.baseVal.value - node[0].y.baseVal.value }))
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('class', 'listener')
    .style("pointer-events", "all");

// interaction without dispatch    

listener.on('mouseover', function() {
        rect.attr('opacity', '0.5')
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(event) {
        rect.attr('opacity', '0.5');

    })
    .on('mousemove', function(event) {
        const points = d3.pointer(event);
        const pointY = points[1];
       
        // what is the current selection 
        const selOne = [rect.nodes()][0].filter((a) => {
            const y = a.y.baseVal.value <= pointY && pointY <= a.height.baseVal.value + a.y.baseVal.value;
            return y;
        });
        //what is the data of the curent selection
        const currData = (selOne.length === 1) ? selOne[0].__data__['id'] : null;
        //conditional statement to control opacity based on current selection
        d3.selectAll('.rectContainer>rect')
            .attr('opacity', ((d, i) => (d.id === currData) ? '1' : '0.5'))

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>


<body>
</body>

<script src="min.js">
</script>

</html>
```

I tried to convert the above to `d3.dispatch` and this is what I tried which did not work

```js
const data = [
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 2 },
    { "id": 3 },
    { "id": 4 },
    { "id": 5 },
    { "id": 6 },
    { "id": 7 },
    { "id": 8 }
];

const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const width = 600;
const height = 450;

const posX = 40;
const posY = 20;
const heightRect = 40;
const widthRect = 40;
const padding = 10;


const svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('xmlns', svgns)
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

const bgRect = svg.append('rect')
    .classed('boundary', true)
    .attr('x', '0')
    .attr('y', '0')
    .attr('width', `${width}`)
    .attr('height', `${height}`)
    .attr('fill', `#E6E6E6`);

//-------------BUILD COLOR SCALE---------------------------//
const interpolatorSequentialMultiHueName = [
    'd3.interpolateViridis'
]

const xColorScale = d3.scaleSequential().domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.id))
    .interpolator(eval(`${interpolatorSequentialMultiHueName[0]}`));

//-------------BUILD RECT---------------------------//   

const rect = svg.append('g')
    .classed('rectContainer', true)
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .join('rect')
    .attr('x', `${posX}`)
    .attr('y', ((d, i) => posY + heightRect * i + padding * i))
    .attr('width', `${widthRect}`)
    .attr('height', `${heightRect}`)
    .attr('fill', (d => xColorScale(d.id)))
    .attr('opacity', '0.5');

//listener
const listener =
    d3.select('rect')
    .clone()
    .raise()
    .attr('x', `${posX}`)
    .attr('y', ((d, i) => { return posY }))
    .attr('width', `${widthRect}`)
    .attr('height', ((d, i) => { const node = rect.nodes(); const len = node.length - 1; return node[len].y.baseVal.value + node[len].height.baseVal.value - node[0].y.baseVal.value }))
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('class', 'listener')
    .style("pointer-events", "all");

//with dispatch
const dispatch = d3.dispatch('one', 'two');

dispatch.on('one', function() {
    this.attr('opacity', '0.5');
});
dispatch.on('two', function(val) {
    this.attr('opacity', (() => {
        return val;
    }))
});
listener.on('mouseover', function() {
        dispatch.call('one', rect)
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
        dispatch.call('one', rect)
    })
    .on('mousemove', function(event) {
        const points = d3.pointer(event);
        const pointY = points[1];
        const selOne = [rect.nodes()][0].filter((a) => {
            const y = a.y.baseVal.value <= pointY && pointY <= a.height.baseVal.value + a.y.baseVal.value;
            return y;
        });
        const currData = (selOne.length === 1) ? selOne[0].__data__['id'] : null;
        const val = (d, i) => (d.id === currData) ? '1' : '0.5';
        dispatch.call('two', d3.selectAll('.rectContainer>rect'))
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>


<body>
</body>

<script src="min.js">
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is just an exercise, because honestly this code is way too cumbersome for production, lots of things here should be refactored.

Regarding your question, the issue is that you're forgetting the value, which is the third argument in `dispatch.call`. But even if you passed `val` that will not work, because you would have the same value for the entire selection.

Thus, pass the `currData`:

```
dispatch.call('two', d3.selectAll('.rectContainer>rect'), currData)
```

And then, in your dispatch:

```
dispatch.on('two', function(currData) {
    this.attr('opacity', (d, i) => (d.id === currData) ? '1' : '0.5')
});
```

Here's your code with those changes:

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 7
  },
  {
    "id": 8
  }
];

const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const width = 600;
const height = 450;

const posX = 40;
const posY = 20;
const heightRect = 40;
const widthRect = 40;
const padding = 10;


const svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('xmlns', svgns)
  .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

const bgRect = svg.append('rect')
  .classed('boundary', true)
  .attr('x', '0')
  .attr('y', '0')
  .attr('width', `${width}`)
  .attr('height', `${height}`)
  .attr('fill', `#E6E6E6`);

//-------------BUILD COLOR SCALE---------------------------//
const interpolatorSequentialMultiHueName = [
  'd3.interpolateViridis'
]

const xColorScale = d3.scaleSequential().domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.id))
  .interpolator(eval(`${interpolatorSequentialMultiHueName[0]}`));

//-------------BUILD RECT---------------------------//   

const rect = svg.append('g')
  .classed('rectContainer', true)
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .join('rect')
  .attr('x', `${posX}`)
  .attr('y', ((d, i) => posY + heightRect * i + padding * i))
  .attr('width', `${widthRect}`)
  .attr('height', `${heightRect}`)
  .attr('fill', (d => xColorScale(d.id)))
  .attr('opacity', '0.5');

//listener
const listener =
  d3.select('rect')
  .clone()
  .raise()
  .attr('x', `${posX}`)
  .attr('y', ((d, i) => {
    return posY
  }))
  .attr('width', `${widthRect}`)
  .attr('height', ((d, i) => {
    const node = rect.nodes();
    const len = node.length - 1;
    return node[len].y.baseVal.value + node[len].height.baseVal.value - node[0].y.baseVal.value
  }))
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('class', 'listener')
  .style("pointer-events", "all");

//with dispatch
const dispatch = d3.dispatch('one', 'two');

dispatch.on('one', function() {
  this.attr('opacity', '0.5');
});
dispatch.on('two', function(currData) {
  this.attr('opacity', (d, i) => (d.id === currData) ? '1' : '0.5')
});
listener.on('mouseover', function() {
    dispatch.call('one', rect)
  })
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    dispatch.call('one', rect)
  })
  .on('mousemove', function(event) {
    const points = d3.pointer(event);
    const pointY = points[1];
    const selOne = [rect.nodes()][0].filter((a) => {
      const y = a.y.baseVal.value <= pointY && pointY <= a.height.baseVal.value + a.y.baseVal.value;
      return y;
    });
    const currData = (selOne.length === 1) ? selOne[0].__data__['id'] : null;
    dispatch.call('two', d3.selectAll('.rectContainer>rect'), currData)
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>


<body>
</body>

<script src="min.js">
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks !!!! Created this only to understand dispatch, not for PROD.

Comment: @smpa01 good to know that! `d3.dispatch` can be useful in some situations, but here a classic `selection.on(...` is the best option.